# How can I specify a range of variables within a SAS function?

Tags: sas

I want to use an IRR function which has the following syntax:

`finance('IRR',var1,var2,var3....,varn);`

How can I apply a range to this? I've tried:

`finance('IRR',var1-var120);`

but it doesn't like it. It thinks there are only 2 arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the variable name list operator `OF`.

```
finance('IRR', OF var1-var120);
```